# How to auto populate a links list based on files in the webserver folder

Tags: javascript, download, directory

I have an issue where by my existing code is reading fixed file links but I would like to have the links autopopulated from the folder depending on the number and names that are in there at the time.

So instead of having to specify the PDF names in the following code I would like to be able to autopopulate the list and then download.

The code works for the prepopulated list but the extra bit stumps.
Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<BODY>
<button onClick="downloadAll(window.links)">Test me!</button>
 <script>                   
var links = [
  'https://example.com/b/bll/invstor/inv1.pdf',
  'https://example.com/b/bll/invstor/inv2.pdf',
  'https://example.com/b/bll/invstor/inv3.pdf',
  'https://example.com/b/bll/invstor/inv4.pdf',
  'https://example.com/b/bll/invstor/inv5.pdf',
];

function downloadAll(urls) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');

  link.setAttribute('download', null);
  link.style.display = 'none';

  document.body.appendChild(link);

  for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    link.setAttribute('href', urls[i]);
    link.click();
  }

  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
        </script>
</BODY>
```

I have this code which draws the directory file of files beginning with INV or DRA.  But I can't get it to talk to the bit var links =

```
set FileSysObj=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFileAndPath = request.servervariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
strFullPath = Server.MapPath("/b/bll/invstor/")
set fldr=FileSysObj.GetFolder(strFullPath)
set FileList = fldr.Files
For Each FileIndex in FileList
if left(FileIndex.Name, 3) = "Inv" or left(FileIndex.Name, 3) = "Dra" then  
Response.Write "https://example.com/b/bll/invstor/" & FileIndex.name

end if
Next
```

Comment: Will need server code to read the directory and create list

Comment: I have added more detail above about how I am trying to get a read of the directory files into the var links part of the code.